# Find the first set of 5 digits in a text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to find the first set of 5 numbers in a text like this :

```
;SUPER U CHARLY SUR MARNE;;;rte de Pavant CHARLY SUR MARNE Picardie 02310;Charly-sur-Marne;;;02310;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

I need to find the first `02310` only.

My regex but it found all set of 5 numbers :

```
([^\d]|^)\d{5}([^\d]|$)
```

Comment: Does `^.*?(\d{5})` help?

Comment: oups sorry no because i don't want the text before.

Comment: So, what do you need to get in the end? What do you want to do with that number?

Comment: this : ;SUPER U CHARLY SUR MARNE;;;rte de Pavant CHARLY SUR MARNE Picardie;Charly-sur-Marne;;;02310;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

Comment: Ok, so you want to remove the number.

Comment: Find `(\d{5}.*)|.` and replace with `$1`. If numbers with more digits may exist or if some other conditions should be checked you have to tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the first 5-digit number you may use

```
^.*?\K(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wnNKWw/1). As you want to remove the match, simply keep the *Replace With* field blank. The `^` matches the start of a line, `.*?` matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and `\K` operator drops the text matched so far. Then, `(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)` matches 5 digits not enclosed with other digits.

Another variation includes a capturing group/backreference:

**Find What**:      `^(.*?)(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)`
**Replace With**: `$1`

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wnNKWw/2).

Here, instead of dropping the found text before the number, `(.*?)` is captured into Group 1 and `$1` in the replacement pattern puts it back.

Answer (score 0):

To find the first 5 digits in the text, you could also match not a digit `\D*` or 1-4 digits followed by matching 5 digits:

```
^(?=.*\b\d{5}\b)(?:\D*|\d{1,4})*\K\d{5}(?!\d)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.*\b\d{5}\b)` Assert that there are 5 consecutive digits between word boundaries
- `(?:\D*|\d{1,4})*` Repeat matching 0+ times not a digit or 1-4 digits
- `\K\d{5}` Forget what was matched, then match 5 digits
- `(?!\d)` Assert what followed is not a digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/79BRw4/1)

Comment: Note that with `\D*`, if there are any digits before the 5-digit number, there will be no match. Lazy dot is preferable in this situation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated it to account for the possible leading digits.

Comment: See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ruB9U0/1). Guess why it breaks? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would've use

```
(^(?:(?!\d{5}).)+)(\d{5})(?!\d)
```

It finds fragment from beginning of the string till end of first 5-digit number, but in case of replacement you can use `$1` or `$2` to substitute corresponding part. For example replacement `$1<$2>` will surround number by `<` and `>`.